# User Has Hat For Something He Never Did Earn

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

So here is a user name [Frank Thornton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2690155/frank-thornton) who has a hat that said that he had earned a silver badge (Werewolf Hunter). I looked at his account and it said that he only has bronze badges, 9 to be exact. I can't seem to find the silver badge that he earned. So my question is how did he possibly have that hat with no silver badges? If he somehow did, where is that silver badge?

Comment: Why would you even care about something like this? How does it matter to your life or the integrity of this site? Hats are nothing more than a lark, and even if he got a head that he "didn't deserve", all I can say is, what the heck. Have fun with it guy.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with being curious. That was just plain old rude to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hat was earned on Super User, not Stack Overflow:

[image: Werewold hunter hat earned by Frank Thornton with Super User icon circled]

You can always see where someone earned hats by clicking on the hats counter in their profile, then selecting individual hats.

They received a [Notable Question badge (silver) on December 15](https://superuser.com/users/245160/frank-thornton?tab=activity) (the first day of the Winter Bash).

Hats, once earned, can be worn anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.